# remove escaping quotes for $_POST symfony

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony

I have 3 forms all very similiar with a wp_editor inside:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
        <label for="mymessage">Message</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <?php wp_editor(
            $mymessage,
            'mymessage',
            array(
                'media_buttons' => false,
            )
        ) ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="mymessage" name="mymessage" value=""/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

On form submit, first the contents of the editor goes into the hidden field using javascript:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(){
        if ($("#wp-mymessage-wrap").hasClass("tmce-active")){
            $('#my_message').val(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
        }else{
            $('#my_message').val($('#mymessage').val());
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Then it goes to the action which is a symfony action `executeUpdate`.
The first line in that action, I output the contents of $_POST.
If I put "hello" as my message, here are the results in each of the forms:

`\"hello\"` - which gets saved as `"hello"` - escaped once - the right way
`\\\"hello\\\"` - which gets saved as `\"hello\"` - escaped twice - an extra slash
`\\\\\\\"hello\\\\\\\"` - which gets saved as `\\\"hello\\\"` - escaped four times - an extra 3 slashes

Magic Quotes is OFF - I outputed phpinfo() and checked.

Why would 3 different forms escape the message differently and how can I make them all be escaped only once?

My form is in wordpress and the action that gets called goes to my api which is symfony.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Access POST data the symfony way:

```
$request->request->get('mymessage')
```

Or do it the right way with FormTypes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the magic quotes.

See the documentation: http://de3.php.net/magic_quotes especially http://de3.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: Please read the question more carefully before answering. I wrote: "Magic Quotes is OFF - I outputed phpinfo() and checked."

Comment: If you are directly printing the contents of $_POST, and it does contain backslashes, and the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` returns false one line later, then probably the Javascript is to blame. Have you checked the POST request data in e.g. Firebug?

Comment: When I look in the Chrome console under "Request Payload" I see the value but without any escaping slashes